# How to animate a svg file g-element?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I am planning to add a big svg file to my website and want to add animation to just a certain group.

The 'train' should move from left to write, out of the frame and back, in a loop, not the background.

How ? (Code below is not the completed one, I cut a huge part to make it suit in here)

```
<svg>
<g id="train">
    <g>
        <path class="st12" d="M88.22,156.12c0,0.7-0.57,1.26-1.26,1.26c-0.7,0-1.26-0.57-1.26-1.26c0-0.7,0.57-1.26,1.26-1.26
                    C87.65,154.86,88.22,155.43,88.22,156.12z"/>
        <path class="st12" d="M86.95,157.61c-0.82,0-1.48-0.66-1.48-1.48c0-0.82,0.66-1.48,1.48-1.48c0.82,0,1.48,0.66,1.48,1.48
                    C88.44,156.94,87.77,157.61,86.95,157.61z M86.95,155.08c-0.58,0-1.05,0.47-1.05,1.05c0,0.58,0.47,1.05,1.05,1.05
                    c0.58,0,1.05-0.47,1.05-1.05C88,155.55,87.53,155.08,86.95,155.08z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st12" d="M93.92,156.12c0,0.7-0.57,1.26-1.26,1.26c-0.7,0-1.26-0.57-1.26-1.26c0-0.7,0.57-1.26,1.26-1.26
                    C93.35,154.86,93.92,155.43,93.92,156.12z"/>
        <path class="st12" d="M92.65,157.61c-0.82,0-1.48-0.66-1.48-1.48c0-0.82,0.66-1.48,1.48-1.48c0.82,0,1.48,0.66,1.48,1.48
                    C94.13,156.94,93.47,157.61,92.65,157.61z M92.65,155.08c-0.58,0-1.05,0.47-1.05,1.05c0,0.58,0.47,1.05,1.05,1.05
                    c0.58,0,1.05-0.47,1.05-1.05C93.7,155.55,93.23,155.08,92.65,155.08z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can use css animations where you are animating the transform translate

Comment: Could you share what you've tried? There are a lot of ways to animate SVGs (javascript, CSS animation, CSS transitions, SMIL) all with pros/cons

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SMIL Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) for SVG.

Adding an `<animateTransform>` element inside the group you wish to animate, with a start and end position outside of the boundaries. Set the `repeatCount` to `infinite` to loop forever.

```
<g id="train">
<animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       begin="0s"
       dur="1s"
       type="translate"
       from="-50 10"
       to="150 10"
       repeatCount="indefinite" 
            />
</g>
```

Here is a simplified working example: https://jsfiddle.net/aloshea/ms0n8dwb/